# convert unicode string for display object with __repr__ on terminal

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, python-2.x

I would like to convert the string `u'Eichst\xe4tt-Landershofen'` for printing the object `station` on terminal.

```
import json

class Station(object):
    def __init__(self,id, name, latitude, longitude):
        self._id = id
        self._name = name
        self._latitude = latitude
        self._longitude = longitude
        ....
    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<object=%s - id=%s, name=%s, latitude=%s, longitude=%s>' \
        % (self.__class__.__name__, self._id, self._name, self._latitude,\
            self._longitude)
```

If I call the `get_name()` function of the object `station` everything is fine. But, If I try to print the whole object with the function `__repr__` I get the following error:

```
print station.Station(id, name, lat, long) 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The string `u'Eichst\xe4tt-Landershofen'` was reading by a file with `encoding='ISO-8859-1'`.

Comment: what do you get when you add `.encode('iso-8859-1')`?

Comment: I get the output: `<object=Station - id=1161, name=Eichst�tt-Landershofen, latitude=48.8779, longitude=11.2347>`. Is it possible to convert  � into a readable character?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: The _source file_ is `iso-8859-1`, but we don't know what encoding has been selected for the terminal. Hopefully, it's `'utf-8'`.

Comment: Does it work when you add `.encode('utf-8')` instead? BTW, you should always add a Python version tag when you ask Unicode questions, since Python 3 handles Unicode quite differently to Python 2.

Comment: If I change `self._name` in function `get_name(self)` to `self_name.encode('UTF-8')`, I get the same output like `.encode('iso-8859-1')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would like to recommend not to use `__repr__` for this in the first place - it's not really intended to be a human-readable representation of the object.  For that you should be looking to `__str__`, `__format__`, and/or `__unicode__`.

Now, your issue is that `__repr__` is returning a unicode object.  This is because when you use a string substitution `'<name %s>' % _name` and `_name` is bound to a unicode object, python 2 automatically "promotes" the bytestring template to a unicode in order to achieve the substitution.

Now, upon seeing a unicode object returned from repr, python will try to get a bytes object back by encoding it using `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which is evidently 'ascii', and fails because the station can't be encoded using an ascii character set.

If you absolutely want the non-ascii characters in your `repr` (why??) you will have to choose an encoding which your terminal understands, and encode to that character set.  Here is an example with utf-8 which will probably work on your system:

```
import json

class Station(object):
    def __init__(self,id, name, latitude, longitude):
        self._id = id
        self._name = name
        self._latitude = latitude
        self._longitude = longitude

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'<object={} - id={}, name={}, latitude={}, longitude={}>'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__, 
            self._id, 
            self.get_name(), 
            self._latitude,
            self._longitude,
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf8')
```